# Como checar se uma sessão existe

Tags: php

Como faço para checar se uma sessão existe e caso ela exista, redirecionar para uma pagina especifica? Tentei da seguinte maneira, mas não esta funcionando.

```
    <?php

      if(isset($_SESSION)){

       header('Location: painel.php');
       exit();

      }
    ?>
```

No caso minha ideia é não deixar o usuário voltar a pagina de login caso ele ja tenha logado no site.

Comment: Caro Jhonatan coloque o `session_start()` no começo do script. Recomendo que estude baseado na documentação: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.session.php, porque ai sim vai aprender o básico de forma mais "correta"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer validar se a sessão não existe, e impedir o carregamento da página pelo usuário, precisa fazer a lógica inversa:

Se a sessão não existe.

```
<?php
// Verifica se a sessão da aba do navegador existe
// Se não existe, inicia.
// Iniciei a função dentro do IF para evitar exibição de erros de cabeçalho

if(!session_id()){session_start();}

// Se não existe, redireciona...
// Verifica se não está definida a sua sessão,
// ou uma sessão específica.

// Exemplo 1:
if(!isset($_SESSION['logado'])
{
    header('Location: pagina_encaminhada.php');
    exit();
}

// Exemplo 2:
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
    header('Location: pagina_encaminhada.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```